# Efficient algorithms for merging hashes into a sparse matrix

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sparse-matrix

I have time data with irregular intervals and I need to convert it to a sparse matrix for use with a graphing library.

The data is currently in the following format:

```
{
  :series1 => [entry, entry, entry, entry, ...],
  :series2 => [entry, entry, entry, entry, ...]
}
```

where `entry` is an object with two properties, `timestamp`(a unix timestamp) and `value`(an integer)
I need to put it in this format in as close to O(n) time as possible.

```
{
   timestamp1 => [ value, value, nil ],
   timestamp2 => [ value, nil, value ],
   timestamp3 => [ value, value, value],
   ...
}
```

Here each row represents a point in time which I have an entry for. Each column represents a series ( a line on a line graph ). Thats why it is very important to represent missing values with nil.

I have some pretty slow implementations but this seems like a problem that has been solved before so I'm hoping that there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Do the timestamps in your output need to be in order?

Comment: @NickBarnes yes, I need them in order eventually but I can just sort them after they're merged.

Comment: Any kind of sort is going to blow your O(n) requirement. But assuming that's not an issue, I'm having a hard time imagining how you'd create the unsorted version any slower than O(n)... Could you give some idea of what your current solution looks like, so we know what we're aiming to beat?

Answer (score 1):

I'm slightly confused by your asking for O(n), so feel free to correct me, but as far as I can tell, O(n) is easily possible.

First find the length of your starting hash (the number of series in the data). This should be O(1), but no worse than O(S) (where S is no of series), and S <= O(n) (assuming no series with no values) so is still O(n).

Store this length somewhere, and then setup your hash for the sparse matrix to automatically initialise any row to an empty array of this size.

```
matrix = Hash.new {|hsh,k| hsh[k] = Array.new(S)}
```

Then simply go through each series, by index. And for each entry, set the appropriate cell in the array to be the right value.

For each entry, this is O(1) (average) for the lookup of the timestamp in the hash, then O(1) for setting the cell in the array. This happens n times, giving you O(n) there.

There will also be the creation of an Array for each row in the matrix. As far as I am aware this is O(1) for one Array, so O(T) (where T is number of timestamps) overall. As we are not creating empty rows where there are no entries with that timestamp, T must be <= n, so this is O(n) as well.

So overall we have O(n) + O(n) + O(n) = O(n). There are probably ways to speed this up in Ruby, but as far as I am aware this is not only close to, but actually O(n).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
num = series.count
timestamps = {}
series.each_with_index do |(k, entries), i|
  entries.each do |entry|
    timestamps[entry.timestamp] ||= Array.new(num)
    timestamps[entry.timestamp][i] = entry.value
  end
end
```

Not sure though about the initial ordering of your series, I guess your real situation is a bit more complex than presented in the question.